# Согласование с числительным, оканчивающимся на слово "одна"

Tags: числительные

Подскажите пожалуйста, верно ли согласованы слова в следующих случаях?

1. Для оставшейся 51 задачи из 100...
2. Из рассматриваемой 51 задачи...
3. Для каждой из 51 обсуждаемой задачи...

Пытался найти что-то похожее в разделе "Имя числительное" в "Русской грамматике" Шведовой, но безуспешно.

Comment: В третьем нет проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Предлагается такая запись:**

*Для оставшихся задач в количестве пятидесяти одной из ста…*

*Из рассматриваемых задач в количестве пятидесяти одной…*

*Для каждой из пятидесяти одной обсуждаемой задачи...*

**Решение компромиссное.**

**Правило 1.** Числительное ***один*** (одно, одна, одни) само по себе и в структуре **составных числительных** по падежу, а также по роду и числу **всегда согласуется с существительным, к которому относится:** сто сорок один карандаш, нет ста сорока одного карандаша, ста сорока одному карандашу, ста сорока одним карандашом, о ста сорока одном карандаше. https://grammatika-rus.ru/osobennoe-chislitelnoe-odin/

**Правило 2.** Русская грамматика под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина, изд. 2, 1990 год, §249

Если в составе количественно-именного сочетания есть **определение**, то оно всегда используется **в форме мн. числа.**

**3.** Использована переходная форма **для обеспечения согласования по числу рядом стоящих слов**.

**Сравнить:** Для оставшихся (мн.ч.) пятидесяти одной задачи (ед.ч.) из ста…